# Submit PDF to server as XFDF. What exactly is getting passed?

Tags: php, pdf, adobe, acrobat, xfdf

Ok so I followed this tutorial to get the PDF submitting to HTML but it seems like a backwards way to do it.

http://koivi.com/fill-pdf-form-fields/tutorial.php

I would like to submit the data as XML so I can then easily map it to a model.

The Adobe documentation is probably the worse I've ever seen.  I followed the submit button documentation but that doesn't tell me anything.  What exactly is getting passed to the server?

[image]

What POST parameter am I looking for?  What name?  What does it look like.  These questions seem basic but I don't see it anywhere.  Thanks.

Comment: You can view what's being sent to the server with `var_dump($_REQUEST)`, `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'))` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XFDF format is described here: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xml/xfdf_2.0.pdf
The body of the POST request contains the XFDF data.